# Pass by Pointer Objective C - Linked List

Tags: objective-c, recursion, linked-list

I am working on this problem to  **return the Kth to Last element of a singly linked list**

I am trying to implement this C solution which passes the value by reference. and do so in Objective C passing by pointer

Currently the code runs infinitely and I am not sure if it is possible in Objective C passing by pointer

C++ Example Code First

[image: C example code]

[image: My example in Objective C]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.  Most notably, we cannot readily reproduce your problem from screen shots.

Comment: Cheap debugging hint: slip a **print** statement into the top of each routine.  Print the routine name and all arguments.  For tracking infinite recursion, also include a global counter: increment at each print, and abort the program when you've hit a useful limit (50 should be plenty here).

Comment: Thank you that is a great idea. I will try that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just out of curiosity, why are you trying to do this in Obj-C? You can compile using C++. I am asking because you don't seem to have a grasp of pass by reference versus pointers. Additionally if you did want to do this in Obj-C, you can still do pass by reference.

In any case you have a few problems with your code:

- Since you've changed to using a pointer, you need to pass the address
  of i.
- Since you are now using a pointer, you have to dereference,
  increment, and reassign your increment
- You did not copy the example
  code properly and used `head` instead of `head->next`

Full code below. I did not compile or double check if it truly runs. Based on visual inspection of your code and the example you provided.

```
- (Node *)nthToLast:(int)k withHead:(Node *)head andCounter:(int *)i {
    // If Node is an Obj-C class, then use nil
    // If Node is a C++ struct/class then use NULL
    // If you have c++11 and it is a C++ struct/class use nullptr
    if (head == nil) {
        return nil;
    }

    Node *nd = [self nthToLast:k withHead:head->next andCounter:i];

    // I've pulled the value in count to make it clear what is being done
    // i++ is pointer arithmetic, which is not what you want to do here
    int count = *i;

    ++count;

    *i = count;

    if (count == k) {
        return head;
    }

    return nd;
}

- (Node *)nthToLast:(int)k withHead:(Node *)head {
    int i=0;
    return [self nthToLast:k withHead:head andCounter:&i];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the same, an hour later.  Let's see whether I can explain this within your working mode ...

Your immediate problem with the loop is that you pass in the address of **i**, but then use that value as if it were the variable's value.  Thus, you're stepping randomly through memory, one word at a time, looking for some word that happens to equal **k**.  This is not likely to happen.  Instead, try

```
i* = i* + 1;
if (i* == k)  {
   ...
```

Or collapse it to:

```
if (++(i*) == k) return head;
```

I assume that you can fix that **head->next** problem without further help.

---

If you *did* use print statements, then you should see a telling effect within your inner calls: that "value" of **i** should be a number of large magnitude, increasing by 4 on each iteration.  When you thought you were incrementing, that step size of 4 is a huge hint that you've segued into pointer arithmetic.